# Cannot download image url without extension with flutter_downloader

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I've been stressing about 2 days to solve this issue. I want to download image and saved within device folder, but it seems it cannot download if the URL is not contains extension.
E.g:

```
https://d24z2kgtjpdfo.cloudfront.net/eyJidWNrZXQiOiJkaWV0a2luZy1wcm9kdWN0aW9uLWFwLW5vcnRoZWFzdC0yIiwia2V5IjoiUG9zdC9pbWFnZWltYWdlY3JvcHBlcjE2ODM1NTY1OTgwMDhqcGctMTY4MzU1NjYwNDg0Ni5qcGciLCJlZGl0cyI6eyJjb250ZW50TW9kZXJhdGlvbiI6eyJtaW5Db25maWRlbmNlIjo3NSwiYmx1ciI6ODB9fX0=
```

I've been using this library `https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader`.

How can I achieve this?

I try manually with dio, and other library too, but it seems doesn't work to.